# Svg not render <path> when added css all:revert

Tags: css, svg

I'm using 3rd party UI library, which is includes such rule:

```
* {all: revert;}
```

then I add svg, but it's not renders, since `width and height` of `<path>` is equal to 0.
I have no ability to remove  `all: revert;` in code (only override).

Here is demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cori-4pgfh

What style need to add to `<path>` to make it visible?

UPD: Here code snippet

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* this cannot be removed  */
body * {
  all: revert; /* this added by 3-rd party library */
}

.svg-wrapper * {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.svg-wrapper path {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M 10,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
                         Q 90,60 50,90
                         Q 10,60 10,30 z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

UPD: When override with `body * { all: initial; }` - doesn't work

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: ...but if you can override `body * {
  all: initial;
}`

Comment: Thankyou,  code snippet added.

If override ``body * {   all: initial; }`` - dosn't work

Comment: perhaps you'd be better off displaying your SVG content via an iframe or object tag.

Answer (score 4):

It's the `d` data (which is also a CSS property now) that gets reset by `all: revert;`, and because CSS properties always override SVG attributes, your `<path>` doesn't contain a shape anymore.

The only fix I could find is to run a script that copies the `d` *SVG attribute* into the `d` *CSS property* on all `<path>` elments:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(path => {
  const data = path.getAttribute('d').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        cssData = `path("${data}")`;
  path.style.d = cssData;
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(path => {
  const data = path.getAttribute('d').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
        cssData = `path("${data}")`;
  path.style.d = cssData;
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* this cannot be removed  */
body * {
  all: revert; /* this added by 3-rd party library */
}

.svg-wrapper * {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.svg-wrapper path {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="svg-wrapper">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M 10,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 50,30
                         A 20,20 0,0,1 90,30
                         Q 90,60 50,90
                         Q 10,60 10,30 z"
        />
      </svg>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Original solution for me. (+) Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

`*:not(path) {all: revert;}` will apply the revert but keep the SVG path intact