# CSS rule not for SVG elements

Tags: css, svg

Never thought I will ask something about CSS but here it is. When you develop a widget you can't rely on particular website's stylesheet so you want something like this:

```
.xxx-widget * {
  all:revert;
}
```

But in case your widget has SVG icons:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 19 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.009 16l18.658-8L.009 0 0 6.222 13.333 8 0 9.778z"></path></svg>
```

reverting all removes also and `d` property from svg and icon disappears. Then I tried to modify reverting selector:

```
.xxx-widget *:not(svg) {
  all:revert;
}
```

Above snippet does not work and at the same time browser does not recognize it as incorrect and a lot of styles are getting broke. Is there any approach to compose selector for everything except svg?

Comment: Of course `.xxx-widget *:not(svg)` does not work: The `d` element inside the `svg` is a descendant of your widget, _and_ it does not have the tag name `svg` - so this selector applies to it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69696234/svg-not-render-path-when-added-css-allrevert

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. First off, CSS affecting SVG `d` attributes (currently) happens in Chromium based browsers. Firefox is yet to follow. (But for most of rest SVG properties it holds that CSS reset affects them.)

I'd try invoking arcane knowledge of CSS [`@namespace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Namespaces):

```html
<style>
/* "page" styles */
p {
 color: orange;
 border: darkorange solid;
}
circle {
 fill: orange;
 stroke: darkorange;
}
</style>

<style>
/* "your" styles not affecting SVG */
@namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
body * {
 all: revert;
}
</style>

<body>

<p>
 This text should be black (or in default UA colour);<br>
 following circle should be orange:
</p>

<svg width="100" viewBox="-4 -4 8 8"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
 <circle r="2" stroke-width="1"></circle>
</svg>
```

Because historically HTML and SVG still possess different namespaces, you can still use it for your advantage.

More examples:

```
<style>
* { /* implicit namespace is not set, so affects both HTML and SVG */ }
</style>

<style>
@namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
@namespace only_html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
@namespace only_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
* {
 /* implicit namespace is set to html, so affects only HTML, not SVG */
}
*|* {
 /* affects elements from any namespace */
}
only_html|* {
 /* affects only HTML elements due explicit namespace */
}
only_svg|* {
 /* affects only SVG elements due explicit namespace */
}
</style>
```

Comment: We're shipping CSS d for SVG in Firefox 97 so we're nearly there.

Comment: @RobertLongson "nearly" is like "close" or "almost" :) good to know though!  here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388998/almost-only-counts-in-horseshoes-and-hand-grenades

Comment: Firefox 97 is scheduled for release on February 8, 2022 [1] and it really should Ship d property and make SVG path d attribute as the presentation attribute [2].
[1] https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Calendar / https://fx-trains.herokuapp.com/release/?version=97
[2] https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1744599

Comment: @myf Perhaps add an example for the `not` which is easily derived from your answer here `<style>
 @namespace only_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
*:not(only_svg|* )  {
 all: revert !important;
}
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<style>
/* "page" styles */
p { color: red; border: solid; }
svg circle { fill: orange; }
</style>

<style>
 @namespace only_svg "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
*:not(only_svg|* )  {
 all: revert !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
 This text should be black (or in default UA colour),
circle should be orange.
</p>
<svg width="100" viewBox="-4 -4 8 8"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
 <circle r="4"></circle>
</svg>
</body>
```

Comment: NOTE: this is a derived example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70424117/125981 from which I borrowed information so I upvoted that

Comment: Well while this is perhaps more readable/understandable, I like setting implicit namespace to HTML and then using plain `*` better, because I think it is closer to OP's intentions.

Technically yes, `:not(svg_namespace|*)` does exactly that and so it would actually match even elements from MathML, what surely is a super niche thing, but I feel it would be unexpected in a similar way affecting SVG with un-namespaced `*` was for OP.